# What is "Optional For" under product related list in salesforce cpq?

Tags: cpq, product, steelbrick

Below is the image of "Optional[image] for" related list , and what is the diff between **options** and **optional for**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optional For means that this is a sub-product that is optional for another product. Optional means that this product has optional sub-products. As a concrete example, a car may have an optional air conditioner (this used to be a thing!). On the car, the Options list would include the air conditioning system. On the air conditioning system, it would be listed as Optional For the car.

Comment: Thank you so much for great response.  Is there any SF documentation related to Optional for?

Comment: @purna I couldn't find any documentation on this, I just intuited this from my knowledge of product management systems in general (I actually helped maintain an ERP for a few years).